# React could I use same Context for multiple form?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-context

I want to use React Context to save the state of my form.
Could I use the same Context for different forms?

Here is my sample code. I use React Hooks API at this sample

In **FormContext.js**

```
...
import {FormReducer} from './FormReducer';

export const FormContext = React.createContext({});

const FormContextProvider = (props) => {

  const formInit = props.value ? props.value : {};

  const [formContext, dispatch] = useReducer(FormReducer, formInit);

  return (
    <FormContext.Provider value={{formContext, dispatch}}>
      {props.children}
    </FormContext.Provider>
  );
}

export default FormContextProvider;
```

my form component **Form.js**

```
...
import {FormContext} from './FormContext';

const Form = ({name, fields}) => {

  const {formContext, dispatch} = useContext(FormContext);

  const inputOnChange = (e, label) => {
    let value = {};
    value[label] = e.target.value;
    dispatch({type:'ChangeField', value: value});
  }

  const renderInputs = () => {
    return fields.map(field => {
      return (
        <div className="field">
          <label>{field}</label>
          <input 
            type="text" 
            value={formContext[field] ?formContext[field]: '' } 
            onChange={(e) => inputOnChange(e, field)} 
            />
        </div>
      )}
    );
  }

  return (
    <div className="form">
      <h3>{name}</h3>
      <form>
        {formContext ? renderInputs() : <React.Fragment/>}
      </form>
    </div>
  );
}

Form.defaultProps = {
  name: '',
  fields: []
}
```

In the **Index.js** I wrap two Form component inside App

```
const formOne = { name: 'Form One', fields: ['username', 'email'] };
const formTwo = { name: 'Form Two', fields: ['name', 'email'] };

<App>
  <Form {...formOne}/>
  <Form {...formTwo}/>
</App>
```

In **App.js**, I have two buttons decide which form should be shown

```
const App = (props) => {

  const [form, setForm] = useState('');

  const formBtnOnClick = (form) => {
    setForm(form);
  }

  const renderForm = () => {

    if (props.children) {
      const selectForm = props.children.find(child => child.props.name.toLowerCase().includes(form));

      if (selectForm) {
        return (
          <FormContextProvider>
            {selectForm}
          </FormContextProvider>
        )
      } else {
        return (<React.Fragment></React.Fragment>);
      }
    }

  }

  return (
    <div className="App">
      App
      <button onClick={(e) => formBtnOnClick('one')}>One</button>
      <button onClick={(e) => formBtnOnClick('two')}>Two</button>

      <Header text="Form" />
      {renderForm()}
      <Header />
    </div>
  );
}
```

When the form changed after the button clicked, but the context didn't rerender,
the value of the previous form still existed. ex: I change the value of email at form, and when I click form two, the email value still existed.

Did I do something wrong or is there a better option for this problem.

Comment: Most of react form libraries do not use form context in the top component. They  insert a context provider into form component. This allows to have separated states for different forms without clearing state manually.

Comment: How should I do exactly?  I wonder why the context will be the same, but if I change the App.js `renderForm()` to `props.children`, those two forms won't have the context problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have to clear the state in this case by `dispatch('CLEAR_FORM')` where it set all value to your defaults

```
case CLEAR_FORM:
      return {
        username: '',
        email: '',
        password: '',
        confirmPassword: '',
      };
```